# out of memory exception android

Tags: android

I have an option to view my application in different languages - English,Tamil and Hindi.I have used customtextview where typeface is being set depending on what language the user wants.

I am getting out of memory exception when the application is used for some time. Is there any direct impact of setting typeface for all the textviews in the application?

Have attached the code snippet of CustomTextView which is extending Textview:

```
  public L10nTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.ttfName = ttfFileName;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    if (ttfName != null) {
        setTypeface(MyApplication.typeFace);
    } else {
        setTypeface(null);
    }

}
```

**Error log:**

```
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2226)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:203)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at com.techjini.tvguide.android.activity.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:94)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at com.techjini.tvguide.android.activity.ProgramNextAiringActivity.onCreate(ProgramNextAiringActivity.java:23)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-15 20:08:50.527: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Without localization feature,my application is working fine and does not crash.

base_layout.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/header_bar_layout" android:visibility="visible"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header_bar" android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/header_click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/before" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/prg_bar"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/header_click" android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/logo_layout" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="visible">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_bar" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/rate_us" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/rate_us" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/like_us" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/fb_like_us" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/follow_us"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter_follow_us" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am setting the locale when the language is changed restart my application. But the memory is not being released and every time my application opens it only increases when finally the app crashes due to low memory.

Setlocale method to change the locale:

```
    public void setLocale(String languageLocaleToLoad) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageLocaleToLoad);

    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();

    config.locale = locale;

    getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}
```

I also found out that the native heap size keeps on increasing whenever the language is changed, and finally the application crashes.

Comment: could you post the layout of your BaseActivity or the layout which is loaded in line 94 of your BaseActivity?

Comment: I suspect your problem is actually somewhere else, i.e. nothing to do with Typefaces. The locale-change is simply bringing a low-memory issue to your attention. What else have you got in memory? You can use DDMS to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) would be helpful in finding out where your memory is going.  Oftentimes, the crash doesn't occur exactly where the real problem is.

http://eclipse.org/mat/

You can dump the memory directly from the DDMS view in Eclipse (use the "update heap" button, and then trigger garbage collection).  It might take a bit to understand the tool, but it's an important one to have in your arsenal.

BTW, I have had an out-of-memory exception problem related to locale too.  My issue was that I reloaded the activity to change the locale, and in one instance it failed to load the new locale and kept reloading until it ran out of memory.

Comment: I have a couple of listviews. When the language is set, I am restarting the application using:
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageNam() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);

But the previous memory allocated is not being released even though the application is reloaded.

Comment: Do you need to go to that effort?  I just do this: Intent restartIntent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
restartIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);
startActivity(restartIntent);
finish();